# Binding ObservableCollection take much time in fact the window take much time to be displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mvvm-light

I'm using **MVVM light** Framework with **WPF** and I have a **DataGrid** that contain all the customers loaded from my SQLite database, But it take too much time to display the Window so if any one can help me for I can dislpay the window and load the DataGrid separately.I think that the Window is taking time because of the DataGrid Binding.

```
 public ObservableCollection<CustumerModel> customerList
    {
        get
        {
            _customerList = new ObservableCollection<CustumerModel>();
            IList<CustumerModel> listCustomer = RemplireListCustomer();
            _customerList = new ObservableCollection<CustumerModel>(listCustomer);
            return _customerList;
        }
```

the method RemplireListCustomer

```
     private IList<CustumerModel> RemplireListCustomer()
    {
        IList<CustumerModel> listCustomer = new List<CustumerModel>();
        foreach (var c in _customerService.GetAllCustomers())
        {
            listCustomer.Add((CustumerModel)c);
        }
        return listCustomer;
    }
```

Comment: We can help you if you help us by showing what code you have in place.

Comment: there is a high chance that you have many rows to be loaded. So in that case you need to show some loading indicator, the code used to load rows should be asynchronous.

Comment: I hope it's more clear with code

Comment: First, u need to implement a custom Observable collection that only sent collectionchanged event once on batch add. And then turn on vertical virtualisation from ur datagrid

Comment: To narrow down the problem, you could change the method RemplireListCustomer() temporarily in way so that is does not access the database, but adds some static content as CustomerModel. If the application is still slow after this change, you know that is its not related to the database access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load your data async by starting a new `Task` in e.g. your class' constructor.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public YourClass()
    {
        TaskEx.Run(() =>
        {
            var listCustomer = RemplireListCustomer();
            CustomerList = new ObservableCollection<CustumerModel>(listCustomer);
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustumerModel> CustomerList { get; private set; }
}
```

And just maybe you do not have to iterate over all customers returned by your service using `foreach`, just return the collection `_customerService.GetAllCustomers()`?